# Rails 3, Devise, Multiple Roles Sharing Same Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm writing a trading system and I have 3 models/roles: Buyers, Sellers and Administrators.  I have generated the devise views for each of the models but I would like to use the same sign in, forgotten password pages etc. for them, rather than maintaining 3 sets of views, is there a way of doing this?

The buyer and seller have similar fields (forename, surname, email address, telephone etc.), is it possible to use STI with devise and is it fairly straightforward?  At the moment I have 3 separate models with no inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have a single User model with a `:role` attribute and also implement a simple ACL via CanCan or `decl_auth` (gems).  This way they will all sign in etc. via the same session.  Devise and CanCan is quite a popular approach and well documented online and in their respective Github wiki's.

For administrators, you can modify your validations to skip on the extra attributes and leave them as blank in the DB.

Comment: Ah I see, so I can use STI for the users.  Is it possible to use different sign up pages for the buyers and sellers using your approach?  The layout and form fields will change based on whether they are a buyer or a seller.

Comment: As per above, the sign in page will be common, but yes, you can customise the sign up page to be different for each.  Get Devise to generate its views and then you can test against `current_user.buyer?` or `current_user.seller?` in your views and load up different partials (for example).

Comment: If you don't want to setup an instance method for each role, you can just do `if current_user.role == 'buyer'` etc...